# Ionic framework customize native keyboard

Tags: ionic-framework

Is it possible to show and customize the native keyboard with Ionic framework?
Lets say for example that I want to show the native keyboard when you come to a state
and I want the keyboard to only contain specific characters (only letter for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the keyboard plugin. Checkout this plugin

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/keyboard/

Comment: I have read about that. But IM looking for a way to force the keyboard to only show specific characters. It doesn't seem possible with this plugin.

Comment: @oderfla That is not possible. You can restrict keyboard to email specific, dialer keyboard etc., which are default

Answer (score 0):

### Input Type Method

Although you cannot change the makeup of the keyboard, you can use different `type` parameters on your input elements to control which type of keyboard mobile devices will show.

For an overview of the different types of inputs, check out [this site](http://mobileinputtypes.com/).

### Return False Method

In addition to changing the type of keyboard that displays, you can also specifically allow or disable certain characters. Accomplish this by checking each keycode as it is typed. For a reference of keycodes, see [here](http://keycode.info/).

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 101){ return false; }">
```

[image: iOS Input Tel]