# Disable emoji option & auto suggestions from ios/android keyboard cordova ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I'am using https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard plugin in one of my ionic project. I have editor screen which I'm opening using window.open function. Can anyone please tell how can I disable emoji option & auto suggestions from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have control over they keyboard, but can request that a certain keyboard be shown such as for search or phone inputs. See my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43667825/3305145):

> ### Input Type Method
>
> Although you cannot change the makeup of the keyboard, you can use different `type` parameters on your input elements to control which type of keyboard mobile devices will show.
>
> For an overview of the different types of inputs, check out [this site](http://mobileinputtypes.com/).
>
> ### Return False Method
>
> In addition to changing the type of keyboard that displays, you can also specifically allow or disable certain characters. Accomplish this by checking each keycode as it is typed. For a reference of keycodes, see [here](http://keycode.info/).
>
> ```
> <input type="text" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 101){ return false; }">
> ```
>
> [image: iOS Input Tel]